# Only show list of items that match all values in different array

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array of selectedCategories and list of products that looks like this:

```
let selectedCategories = []
let productList = []
```

and a JSON list of products which looks like this:

```
let products = [ 
    { 
        "id": 1, 
        ...
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 1", "count": 1 }, 
            { "name": "Category 2", "count": 1 }, 
            { "name": "Category 3", "count": 1 } 
        ], 
        ...
    }, 
    { 
        "id": 2, 
        ...
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 4", "count": 1 },
            { "name": "Category 5", "count": 2 }, 
            { "name": "Category 6", "count": 1 } 
        ], 
        ... 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": 3, 
        ...
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 5", "count": 1 } 
        ], 
        ...
    } 
]
```

I only want to show the products that match the values in the selectedCategories array. I've tried both every and includes, but cannot seem to get the desired result:

```
this.products.filter(product => {
    product.categories.filter(category => {
        if (this.selectedCategories.includes(category.name)) {
            productList.push(product)
        }
    })
})
```

and

```
this.products.filter(product => {
    product.categories.filter(category => {
        this.selectedCategories.every(value => {
            if (value === category.name) {
                productList.push(product)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

The problem is that in the code above, it doesnt check if all values in the array match, but only if it occurs.

Wished output is something like:

```
selectedCategories = [ "Category 5" ]
>>> productList = [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]

selectedCategories = [ "Category 5", "Category 4" ]
>>> productList = [{id: 2}]
```

How can i achieve this?

Edit:

How can i filter on multiple arrays in the product object?
Product structure:

```
[ 
    { 
        "id": 1, 
        ...
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 1", "count": 1 }, 
            { "name": "Category 2", "count": 1 }, 
            { "name": "Category 3", "count": 1 } 
        ],
        "styles": [
            { name: "Style 1", count: 1 },
            { name: "Style 2", count: 1 },
        ] 
        ...
    }, 
    { 
        "id": 2, 
        ...
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 4", "count": 1 },
            { "name": "Category 5", "count": 2 }, 
            { "name": "Category 6", "count": 1 } 
        ],
        "styles": [
            { name: "Style 3", count: 1 },
            { name: "Style 4", count: 1 },
        ] 
        ... 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": 3, 
        ...
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 5", "count": 1 } 
        ],
        "styles": [
            { name: "Style 3", count: 1 },
        ] 
        ...
    } 
]
```

Expected output:

```
selectedCategories = [ "Category 5" ]
>>> productList = [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]

selectedCategories = [ "Category 5", "Style 3" ]
>>> productList = [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]

selectedCategories = [ "Category 5", "Style 3", "Style 4" ]
>>> productList = [{id: 2}]
```

Comment: do you want to filter `category` as well?

Comment: Don't really need to. Was just the easiest way to isolate each object in the array.

Comment: Neither of your filter() has a boolean return and you aren't trying to store the result of the outer filter so all you are using it for is to create loops and that is not how filter is used. You are basically using it as `forEach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `filter`+`every`+`some`+`map` to get your desired output:

```js
const products = [ { "id": 1, "categories": [ { "name": "Category 1", "count": 1 }, { "name": "Category 2", "count": 1 }, { "name": "Category 3", "count": 1 } ], "styles": [ { name: "Style 1", count: 1 }, { name: "Style 2", count: 1 }, ] }, { "id": 2, "categories": [ { "name": "Category 4", "count": 1 }, { "name": "Category 5", "count": 2 }, { "name": "Category 6", "count": 1 } ], "styles": [ { name: "Style 3", count: 1 }, { name: "Style 4", count: 1 }, ] }, { "id": 3, "categories": [ { "name": "Category 5", "count": 1 } ], "styles": [ { name: "Style 3", count: 1 }, ] } ];

const selectedCategories = [ "Category 5", "Style 3", "Style 4" ]

const result = products.filter(p=>selectedCategories.every(k=>p.categories.some(t=>t.name==k) || p.styles.some(s=>s.name==k))).map(({id})=>({id}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! If i in the future adds multiple filterable parameters, how can i incorporate them into the every method? For example. styles: `[{name: "round, count: n}]`

Comment: @DanielK If so then you need to make the changes in `some` method.

Comment: I'm quite new to JavaScript, could you give me an example? Lets say the product object structure is something like `{id: 1, categories: [ { "name": "Category 1", "count": 1 }, { "name": "Category 2", "count": 1 }], styles: [{ name: "Style 1", count: 1}]}`. The selectedCategories structure remains the same.

Comment: @DanielK Can you edit your question with given data and expected output?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @DanielK Updated my answer have a look.

Comment: Cheers! Marked your answer as correct now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the use of `filter` and `every`

```
const getProductList = (products, selectedCategories) => {
  return products
    .filter((product) => {
      const productCategories = product.categories.map(
        (category) => category.name
      )
      return selectedCategories.every((selectedCategory) =>
        productCategories.includes(selectedCategory)
      )
    })
    .map((product) => ({ id: product.id }))
}
```

**Full demo**

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    categories: [
      { name: "Category 1", count: 1 },
      { name: "Category 2", count: 1 },
      { name: "Category 3", count: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    categories: [
      { name: "Category 4", count: 1 },
      { name: "Category 5", count: 2 },
      { name: "Category 6", count: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    categories: [{ name: "Category 5", count: 1 }],
  },
]

const getProductList = (products, selectedCategories) => {
  return products
    .filter((product) => {
      const productCategories = product.categories.map(
        (category) => category.name
      )
      return selectedCategories.every((selectedCategory) =>
        productCategories.includes(selectedCategory)
      )
    })
    .map((product) => ({ id: product.id }))
}

console.log(getProductList(products, ["Category 5"]))
console.log(getProductList(products, ["Category 5", "Category 4"]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` (either with the `return` keyword or with the implicit return of arrow functions) inside the array methods for them to be useful. After filtering, `.map` each to an object containing only the ID:

```js
const getFiltered = (selectedCategories) => {
  const productList = products
    .filter(({ categories }) => selectedCategories.every(
      requiredCat => categories.some(
        prodCat => prodCat.name === requiredCat
      )
    ))
    .map(({ id }) => ({ id }));
  console.log(productList);
};

const products = [ 
    { 
        "id": 1, 
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 1", "count": 1 }, 
            { "name": "Category 2", "count": 1 }, 
            { "name": "Category 3", "count": 1 } 
        ], 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": 2, 
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 4", "count": 1 },
            { "name": "Category 5", "count": 2 }, 
            { "name": "Category 6", "count": 1 } 
        ], 
    }, 
    { 
        "id": 3, 
        "categories": [ 
            { "name": "Category 5", "count": 1 } 
        ], 
    } 
];

getFiltered(['Category 5', 'Category 4']);
getFiltered(['Category 5']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the cateories as well.

```js
const
   filterByCategories = (products, categories) =>
       products.filter(product =>
            categories.every(category =>
                product.categories.some(c => category === c.name)
            )
       ),
   products = [{ id: 1, categories: [{ name: "Category 1", count: 1 }, { name: "Category 2", count: 1 }, { name: "Category 3", count: 1 }] }, { id: 2, categories: [{ name: "Category 4", count: 1 }, { name: "Category 5", count: 2 }, { name: "Category 6", count: 1 }] }, { id: 3, categories: [{ name: "Category 5", count: 1 }] }];

console.log(filterByCategories(products, ["Category 5"])); [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]
console.log(filterByCategories(products, ["Category 5", "Category 4"])); [{id: 2}]
```